# How to add multiple translation files for the same language in Android?

Tags: android

My app targets different audiences in various branches, which shall use the same app, but with different translation files. For instance, some users need a more specific description of certain parts of the app, which won't be relevant for users within another branch.

My app structure looks like this:

```
 MyProject/
     res/
       values/
            strings.xml
```

I know that each language can has its own strings.xml file, but I want to have multiple strings.xml files within a language (like en_**UK** or en_**USA**). For instance I would like to create a fake country code **en_LAW** as translation file for users working as lawyers.

The following code shall then be used to set the custom translation variant:

```
   public static void setLocale(Activity activity, String languageCode) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageCode);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Resources resources = activity.getResources();
        Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
        config.setLocale(locale);
        resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

The only problem is that I haven't found a way of creating and letting android studio recognise custom country codes. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2):

The Android API doesn't directly support multiple translations for the same string in the same language. You will need to implement your own logic to handle this. One solution that comes to mind is that you have multiple strings say `explanation` and `explanation_lawyer` then your app logic decides which of these strings to display. Both strings have translations as normal.

Comment: First of all thanks for your quick answer, but if it is not possible to create multiple translations within a language, is there at least a way of creating a own fake language? My app includes to many different translation strings, which would make it very confusing if I had to change the strings within the app.

Comment: @DeveloperCat1234 Perhaps it is possible to create your own language names, but that seems like the wrong way to solve this problem. A better solution is to build your own system that decides which strings are displayed for a given user. Yes, this will be a lot of work, but as you build it, you should look for abstractions that help ease the pain.