# How to create an android translation file for a custom, non-existent language?

Tags: android

**Goal:**
I want to create a custom language for Android, which shall be used for the **strings.xml** translation file, but I haven't found a way of letting the **translation editor** of Android Studio recognize my custom language. For instance, I want to create the language code **lang123** which shall be regognized by android as a custom language:

```
MyProject/
     res/
       values/
            strings.xml
       values-lang123/
            strings.xml
```

**I then would like to use the following code sniped for changing the language:**

```
 public static void setLocale(Activity activity, String languageCode) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageCode);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Resources resources = activity.getResources();
        Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
        config.setLocale(locale);
        resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

**Why do I want to do it?**
It's a possible solution to one of my other questions: [How to add multiple translation files for the same language in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65514067/how-to-add-multiple-translation-files-for-the-same-language-in-android/65515041)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65514067/how-to-add-multiple-translation-files-for-the-same-language-in-android/65515041#comment115826970_65514099) seems like a better solution.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have read and considered this answer already, but I think it would be easier to create a custom language instead.